# A question regarding the boundary operator

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading Hatcher's Algebraic topology book, and on page 106 the boundary homomorphism $\partial_{n}:\Delta_{n}(X) \to \Delta_{n-1}(X)$ is defined on its basis elements as:
\begin{equation*}
    \partial ([v_{0}, v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}]) = \sum_{i} (-1)^{i}[v_{0}, v_{1}, \dots, \hat{v_{i}}, \dots, v_{n}]
\end{equation*}
where $\hat{v_{i}}$ indicates that vertex $v_{i}$ is deleted from the simplex.
In his definition, he doesn't require the simplices to be oriented. From my understanding, the signs in the boundary operator are there to impose an orientation on the simplices. However, some sources demand oriented simplices, with the same formula. In my opinion, this requirement is redundant because as I stated earlier the formula "gives" orientation to the simplices. Am I right? Also, when defining n-chains (formal sum of n-simplices with integer coefficients) do we require orientation of the simplices so the sum makes sense? (without orientation it is not clear what is the sum of two simplices with different coefficients)

Another question that I have is that if the field is $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$, we change the formula to just the sum of the faces:
\begin{equation*}
    \partial ([v_{0}, v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}]) = \sum_{i} [v_{0}, v_{1}, \dots, \hat{v_{i}}, \dots, v_{n}]
\end{equation*}
Is that correct?

Comment: The orientation that is provided in the definition of the boundary operator is only relative to the orientation of the original simplex, and it turns out that is all that is need to calculate homology. And yes, your assumption about $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients is completely right, this does make calculations in this field much easier.

Comment: "In his definition, he doesn't require the simplices to be oriented." That's not true. When you order the vertices of the simplex like this: $[v_0, v_1, \dots, v_n]$, you are already inducing an orientation on the simplex (and hence on all of its subsimplices).

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. So in the boundary operator definition, we must require that the simplex is oriented. What about n-chains?